# What does AccessibilityNodeInfo represent?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am working on an android project and was trying to understand what AccessibilityNodeInfo represents. I am a novice and just started developing in android, so I am not finding the explanation on the Android Developers useful!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html "This object allows you to request view layout hierarchy (parents and children) of the component that originated the accessibility event. This feature allows an accessibility service to investigate the full context of an event, including the content and state of any enclosing views or child views. "

Comment: clarifications: more precisely, what is the relationship between AccessibilityWindowInfo and AccessibilityNodeInfo?

Comment: A window is a system-level container for UI. Activities and dialogs are common windows. A node is a widget or container in a window.